# Regular Expression match for exact string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string

```
%24p1_x=-5&%24p1_y=-285.06492367689526&%24p1_hei=0.617986639129584&%24
```

And want to change p1_x value as dynamic

`15.23` value calculated dynamically

Need Output as:

```
%24p1_x=-15.23&%24p1_y=-85.06492367689526&%24p1_hei=0.617986639129584&%24"
```

I tried with explode using "&" and preg_match to match the string.
Could anyone help how to achieve that?

```
    <?php

$a = '%24p1_x=-5&%24p1_y=-285.06492367689526&%24p1_hei=0.617986639129584&%24';

echo $a.'<br/><br/>';
$b = explode("&", $a);

foreach($b as $key => $val){
    if(preg_match('/p1_x/', $val)){
        echo 'Matched';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please post the exact attempt that you made, there is not enough information here to help at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you just want a simple `preg_replace`:

```
$new_val = -15.23;
print preg_replace('/(p1_x).*?&/', '\1='.$new_val.'&', $a);
```

The expression /(p1_x).*?&/  means search for the smallest number of characters from p1_x to an &.

The \1 in the replacement is equal to the first part in brackets from the search expression.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing just the `p1_x` value with `$n`, upto the next `&`

```
preg_replace('/p1_x=[^&]*/', 'p1_x=' . $n, $a)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer wiil check